# Sifr causes background image to flicker on page load

Tags: sifr

Basically every time you refresh the page the browser clears the screen so it's completely white, then paints everything real fast.  This causes a noticeable jump when switching pages or refreshing a page.  It is most noticeable in FF and least noticeable in safari with IE being in the middle.

Is this fixable or just a con to using Sifr?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a con to using Flash to render text. Have you considered using a server side language to generate text or [typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) ?

Or better still, can you use a web safe font, or is the client the type that won't budge?

### Edit

You may be talking about FOUC ... Flash of unstyled content. This generally is an IE issue with stylesheet placement, but I've seen in it Safari before too. There are generally workarounds for this.